# How to set an image to a NSButton to be resized along with the button?

Tags: objective-c, image, macos, cocoa, nsbutton

I have an image (3width x 15height, the first and last pixels are rounded on the corners), and I want to create a button (the height of the button is always the same, 15px, but the width changes) that uses this image no matter what size it is, kinda like `UIEdgeInsets` on iOS.
I've tried to use `[[button cell] setImageScaling:NSImageScaleAxesIndependently];` but the image gets distorted and loses quality.
How can I do this on OSX? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that as the button gets wider, of the 3 columns of pixels (since the image is 3 pixels wide), you would like the central column of pixels to be "stretched" and repeated while the very left and very right columns of pixels remain the same?

Comment: yes, it's exactly that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably create a custom subclass of `NSButtonCell` and use the Application Kit's [NSDrawThreePartImage()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSDrawThreePartImage) function in the cell's [`drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCell/drawInteriorWithFrame%3ainView%3a) method.

For more info on how to use `NSDrawThreePartImage()`, see [Cocoa Drawing Guide: Drawing Resizable Textures Using Images](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Images/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH208-SW35).

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to set this in graphical interface > Attribute Inspection > Button section Background